# Boost phrase match when all words of query are present in solr search field

Tags: solr

I was trying to search query="Norwegian seafood" and I have many records containing query words.

Schema for the phrase field is:

```
<field name="phrase_field" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I want to boost the match which contain both words (Norwegian and seafood) and synonyms like norway.

Comment: Documents that match both terms will be scored higher by default; there shouldn't be a need to apply an additional boost. But if you want to boost documents where those terms appear close to each other more, you can look at `pf2` and `pf3` to the edismax handler, or apply an explicit proximity boost.

Comment: I have match like "seafood in Norway" and it's coming at 4th position. I want it in 1st position.

Comment: Sure, but if you have both terms in the document, it _should be scored higher_. You'll have to include information from debug query (it'll show you how the query is scored) and what your actual query looks like. `q=norway seafood` should usually give you documents that contain both terms above those that only contain one of them.